# Python script to write exception.KeyError to text file

Tags: python

### I have nested dictionary as following:

```
Dict1 | level 1-1  | level 2-1-1 | level 3-1-1-1 | core [1]
                                                 | core [2]
                                                 | core [3]
                                 | level 3-1-1-2 | core [1]
                                                 | core [2]
                   | level 2-1-2 | level 3-1-2-1 | core [1]
                                                 | core [2]
                                 | level 3-1-2-2 | core [1]
      | level 1-2  | level 2-2-1 | level 3-2-1-1 | core [1]
                                 | level 3-2-1-2 | core [1]
                   | level 2-2-2 | level 3-2-2-1 | core [1]
                                                 | core [2]
                                 | level 3-2-2-2 | core [1]
```

### ..........

level 1 would be my **key**
level 2 would be my **key1**
level 3 would be my **key2**
core would be my **value2** for key2
core and level 3 would be my **value1** for key1
core, level 3, and level 2 would be my **value** for key

When the script was executed, there were some errors, specifically KeyError of **key2**.  I came up with couple lines to put this exception to a log.txt file.  ie:

```
except KeyError:
  save_to_log (time_stamp, sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1])
  continue
```

However, it can only output the **key2** information.  I would like to be able to output the **key** information in respect to the **key2** so that I can easily identify the fault in the original file.  Is this possible in Python?  Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: oops.  I noticed the format has changed a little and this may confuse people who tries to read the question.  Here's a example of what I'm trying to say:  I have a bookstore which has 100 books in it.  Each book has between 5 to 30 chapters, which then has between 1 to 10 paragraphs.  Now my program encounters an error saying that one of the paragraph is missing, but this paragraph can be in any chapter or any book.  Once the paragraph is identified, is there a way Python can output the chapter and book info to a text file instead of just the paragraph info?  Thanks

Comment: My favorite trick to avoid nested dicts/lists is to index a dict with a tuple. So you can say `bookstore = {}; bookstore[book,chapter,paragraph] = "blah"`. This vastly simplifies this sort of thing.

Comment: If you do it this way, how do you "link" the book to the chapter then to the paragraph?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by link here. Under my scheme, you have to have the book, chapter, and paragraph identifiers "in hand" in order to look up the paragraph. Can you explain your use case and your error case a bit more? You're getting a KeyError on key2; where is your key2 coming from?

Comment: For "key" (bookstore) I have many "value" (books). Then I make each book a "key1" with many "value1" (chapters). Then I make each chapter a "key2" with many "value2" (paragraphs). If a chapter is missing ("key2" or "value1"), script gives me a exception.KeyError for "key2" and log it to a file. But I have many books with the same chapter number. I want to know if there is a way I can id the "key1" based on the "key2". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to debug by stepping through with [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)

Comment: the bug is not in the script but in the text file script modifies.  that's why I'm wondering if Python will be able to identify "which book" is missing the paragraph so we can go replace "the book".  Thanks for the feedback though.